# ¿Comó crear una vista en Django con los resultados de una condición?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Quiero crear una lista donde se muestren los nombres de los usuarios que tienen su status "Activo"

¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo le puedo hacer?

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre' , max_length=250, null = False, blank = False,)
    imag = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", null=True, blank=True, upload_to="Clientes")
    description =  models.CharField(verbose_name='Descripcion',máx_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status',max_length=10)
```

Esta es la view:

```
def clients_list(request):
 lista_clients = Clients.objects.filter(status='Activo')

 return render(request, "core/index.html", {'lista_clients': lista_clients})
```

Esta es template:

```
 <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                          <li><a href="/#header">Inicio</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/#services">Servicios</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#software-factory">Fábrica de software</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#outsourcing">Consultoría</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#contacts">Contáctenos</a></li>
                            {% block content %}
                            <ul id="Submenu">
                                 <li>{% for clientes in lista_clientes %}<a href="">{{ clientes.name }}</a> {% endfor %}
                                
                            </ul>
                            {% endblock %}
```

Estas son las url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', core_views.index, name = "index" ),
    path('newTicket',views_support.supportDesk, name = "support" ),
```

Comment: Muestra el archivo de views, el template y el error.

Answer (score 1):

Sería con un:

```
list(Clients.objects.filter(status='Activo'))
```

Con eso te traería los que son 'Activo' en una lista

En lo personal escogería booleandField, para el tema de status y asignarlo tal cual con un boleano, claro quiero pensar que en status solo existirán dos valores: 'Activo' 'inactivo'

```
status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Status', max_length=10, default=True)
```

Espero y sea de tu ayuda, si no es exactamente lo que querías, comentame.

Comment: asi mas o menos lo estoy realizando en el views pero me marca error, este es el codigo: def clientes_list(request):
 lista_clientes = Clients.objects.filter(status='Activo')
return render(request, "core/index.html", {'lista_clientes': lista_clientes})

Comment: Podrías mostrar que error te da ?

Comment: no me muestra en el html nada,  {% block content %} {% for clients in lista_clientes %}
                            <ul id="Submenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">{{ clients.name }}</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                            {% endfor %} {% endblock %}

Comment: ¿Creés qie pudieras publicar una captura de tu template, de tu view y urls?

Answer (score 1):

Estas creando un CharField y esto no es bueno. Seria mejor un BooleanField

yo lo haría de esta manera.

Modelo

```
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

vista

```
def clients_list(request):
 lista_clients = Clients.objects.filter(status=True)
```

template

```
{% for client in lista_clientes %}
    {{ client.name }}
    {{ client.description}}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Puedes  filtrar un CharField a traves de Q

Modelo

```
status = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status',max_length=10)
```

Vistas

```
 lista_clients = Clients.objects.filter(Q(status__icontains=Activo),
```

Si vas a usar una CharFiend te recomiendo que uses un choices Ej:

```py
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Activo', ('Activo')),
    ('Privado',('Privado')),
    )
```

```py
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Activo', max_length=20, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estás llamando la vista incorrecta.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', core_views.index, name = "index" ),
    path('newTicket',views_support.supportDesk, name = "support" ),
```

En ninguna URL llamas tu client_list.

Tienes que agregar algo como:

```py
path('list', app.client_list, name="list")
```

O si quieres incluirlo en core_views.index, de alguna forma tienes que llamar la función client_list en core_views.index y pasar los datos en tu diccionatrio de contexto a tu función render.